# Proof - Number of pairs in a cartesian product set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am attempting to prove that $${n+1 \choose 2}+{n \choose 2} = n^2$$ in a combinatorial way. I start by using a set $N=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and stating that $\vert N\times N\vert=n^2$. Then I want to partition the set of the cartesian product into two subsets which contain

(I) The pairs $(s,t)$ where $s<t$

(II) The pairs $(s,t)$ where $s>t$ or $s=t$

There is a solution to the problem proving (II) by introducing a new set $N\cup\{x\}$ where $x$ is a new symbol. I find this way a little confusing and was wondering if the following way is correct. For simplicity, I use the set $N=\{1,2,3\}$ but this applies for any set $N$ defined above.

In the image below, the blue lines depict partition (I) and it shows clearly that you can only form this partition having ${n \choose 2}$ elements. The red lines show how to create (II). Since an element can choose itself or another less than it, then there are ${n \choose 2} + n = {n+1 \choose 2}$ elements in (II).

[image]

Is this reasoning using the image correct, and is there additional information that can be added to this proof that show how the respective partitions have those many elements?

Comment: The number of ordered pairs of the form $(s, t)$, with $s \leq t$, is $\binom{n}{2} + n$, where the term $\binom{n}{2}$ counts those pairs in which $s < t$ and $n$ counts those pairs in which $s = t$.  While it is true that $\binom{n}{2} + n = \binom{n + 1}{2}$, your justification for your claim that there are $\binom{n + 1}{2}$ such pairs is not clear to me.

Comment: Thank you, edited that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning for I is correct.  You select two elements of $n$ without replacement in $n \choose 2$ ways, then order them with $s$ the smaller and $t$ the larger.  For II, clearly the number of pairs where $s \gt t$ is $n \choose 2$ by the previous argument.  There are $n$ pairs where $s=t$.  Now ${n \choose 2}+n=\frac 12n(n-1)+n=\frac 12n(n+1)={n+1 \choose 2}$.  You can decide if that is too much algebra to claim it is a combinatoric argument.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind explaining why the combination operation is used over permutation? Aren't combinations impartial to ordering when what we're looking for is strict ordering for pairs $(s,t)$ with $s<t$ (and vice-versa)?

Comment: Your equation uses combinations, so that is what we want.  To me, a combinatoric argument is one that rests on counting something in two different ways.  $n^2$ is the number of ways of selecting two ordered things out of $n$ with replacement.  We need to break that into two pieces, one of which is $n \choose 2$ and the other is ${n+1 \choose 2}$.  The pairs with the first element less are a good choice for $n \choose 2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. There's a proof without words. Here it is for $n=3$:

```
x y y
x x y
x x x
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach for (II) is to observe that $s>t$ or $s=t$ is equivalent to $s+1>t$.

More precisely, if 
$$A= \{ (s,t) : 1 \leq t \leq s \leq n \}$$ and
$$B= \{ (s',t) : 1 \leq t < s' \leq n+1 \}$$
then
$$f(s,t)=(s+1,t)$$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: I sort of see it, thank you. So therefore $card(B)$ is $(n+1)C2$?